# Azure SQL versioning

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

While working to restore some SQL 2017 DBs to my Azure SQL DB for some testing we ran into an issue where Azure SQL is running a lower engine version than the VM we pulled the DBs from. Is there a way to change the engine version of an Azure SQL DB or is that hardcoded? If it is hardcoded than would my best option to be a table copy to get the data in and not worry so much about versioning?

Comment: With Azure SQL DB, `@@version` doesn't return accurate results, because of some sort of historical compatibility baggage. SQL DB will always report major version 12--even though it's newer than version 15 of the on prem version.

Answer (score 1):

Azure sql Database is **versionless**. The version number that you get from @@version variable is 12.x (like sql server 2014 on prem) but it is not related to the engine and features.

**Versionless** means that microsoft does not release major versions of SQL Server in Azure SQL. They are continuously updating the software that powers Azure SQL to give us the latest updates and enhancements.

To copy a table from Azure sql databases there are variuos techniques.
I suggest you to use a ssis packages.

Comment: Is it possible to sync DBs from Azure SQL to a VM based SQL instance? They are in the same subnet and have access to one another currently

Comment: yes, take a look here: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-set-up-azure-data-sync-between-azure-sql-databases-and-on-premises-sql-server/ consider your vm like an on premise sql instance